# Connecting Two ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listview

I'm trying to use two listviews (that are on same page - wpf) to display info about a group class. In the first Listview I want to display the group # and group size(using gridview) and in the second listview I want to display the first name and last name of each person that is in the group that I have selected in the first listview box. Both listviews are using gridviews. I have one observableCollection that the first listview is binded to. Do I make another observablecollection to bind to the second listview. If so how do I connect the two collections? I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help is greatly greatly appreciated.

xaml:

```
   <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,12" x:Name ="listViewGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupNumber}" Width="40">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="GroupNumber" Content="#" Click="SortClick" />
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupLeader}" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="GroupLeader" Content="Group Leader" Click="SortClick" />
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupSize}" Width="70">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="GroupSize" Content="Group Size" Click="SortClick" />
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

            <Label Content="Leader" Height="28" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="lblFirstName" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.GroupLeader, ElementName =listViewGroups}" Height="23" Margin="12,31,0,0" Name="txtFirstName" MaxWidth="160" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" />
            <Label Content="Group Members" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,60,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" />
            <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,80,188,12" x:Name ="listViewGroupMembers" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Name" Content="First Name" Click="SortClick" />
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" Width="80">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Name" Content="Last Name" Click="SortClick" />
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Group Class:

```
public class Group
{

    public List<Camper> members;
    private String name;
    public static int groupCount = 0; 
    private static int optimalSize = 8;



    public string GroupNumber { get; set; }

    public string GroupLeader { get; set; }

    public int GroupSize { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get { return "Testing"; } set { } }

    public string LastName { get; set; } 

    public Group()
    {        
        this.members = new List<Camper>();
        this.name = "Group " + groupCount;
        groupCount++;
    }
}
```

In the Mainwindow : this click event below has to do with a custom button that is on a toolbar i made. When I click the button Groups are customly made.

```
   ObservableCollection<Group> bind = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        allGroups = AssignRelationshipValues.assignGroups(allCampers);
       ObservableCollection<Camper> groupCampers = new ObservableCollection<Camper>();

        bind.Groups.Clear();

        for (int g = 0; g < allGroups.Count; g++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < allGroups[g].members.Count; i++)
            {
                groupCampers.Add(allGroups[g].members[i]);

            } bind.Groups.Add(new Group { GroupNumber = allGroups[g].getName(), GroupSize = allGroups[g].getOptimalSize(), Members = groupCampers });

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, what you'd want is for your second `ListView` to be bound like so:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.members, ElementName=listViewGroups}" />
```

Similar to what you have on your `TextBox` that's bound to `GroupLeader`.  Also, Shouldn't `FirstName` and `LastName` be properties on the `Camper` class rather than on the `Group` class?  They would have to be in order for this to work if I'm understanding what you're after.

Some clarification: What this binding is saying is "Go to the 'listViewGroups' `ListView` and get the `SelectedItem`".  This will be a `Group` object, since `listViewGroups` is bound to a collection of `Group` objects.  Then it will try to find a property on the selected `Group` item called `members`, which is your `List<Camper>` - which you'll probably want to change to an `ObservableCollection`.  Then anything inside your second `ListView` will then reference the objects in the collection it's bound to (`Group.members`) to resolve bindings, which means it will look for `FirstName` and `LastName` on the `Camper` objects within `members`.

You can go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) for further explanation from MSDN about Silveright/WPF databinding.

Comment: I do have FirstName and LastName in the camper class, If I use those properties I would bind the second listview to Camper then right? Everything I try isn't really working. Also what would be members when you say SelectedItem.members? Really appreciate your time and replies. I need to figure this out soon. I'm running out of time.

Comment: I think I'm prlly confusing myself in the actual code part more than anything though. I don't really know what I'd have to code.

Comment: Looking at your code I see there's `Group` and each `Group` has a `List<Camper>` called `members`.  I assumed it was the `Camper` objects in `members` you wanted to display in the second listview, so that's what `SelectedItem.members` refers to in the binding.

Comment: On looking at it again though, you need to make `members` a property (with a getter and setter) rather than just a field in order to bind to it.

Comment: Right just did. But then how does FirstName and LastName work. I have those properties in Camper, but as of now I also have it in Group. Should I actually get and set something for members rather than saying just get; set; ?

Comment: Also the members property is in Group which is the observableCollection. How does the itemsource of the 2nd listview know where to get members from?

Comment: Thinking about this again, I may have misled you.  You might try this: `<ListView DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listViewGroups}" ItemsSource="{Binding members}" />`

Comment: Ok I'm getting invisible items in the second listview. At least I'm getting something though. Also the observablecollection would be of List<Camper> right? Like this: ObservableCollection<List<Camper>> members {get; set; }

Comment: Alright I'm really close. I'm getting the names to display but im getting ALL!! the names, Instead of just getting the names that are in the current selected group